# Soloing Dungeons or How To Stop Those Pesky NPCs From Tagging Along

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to stop NPCs from tagging along when I am doing their quests in Skyrim?

I have been playing as a stealth character and am finding that the NPCs that want to accompany me on these missions (in particular, the Companions) keep getting in the way, pulling mobs before I'm ready, or bumping me when I am taking a shot causing a miss. They're more a hindrance than a help, so I'm looking for a way to prevent them from coming along?

I understand there is a method to stop followers, but I'm not sure this is the same thing. I'm playing vanilla Skyrim with no addons.

Is there any way to do this?

Edit: I don't believe this is a duplicate. The indicated previous question was about getting a quest follower to stop following on an abandoned or postponed quest. This question is about preventing an NPC or NPCs accompanying the player in a dungeon/quest.

Note the quests I've had the most trouble with NPCs on is the Companions quests, but I'd prefer to not be accompanied on any.

Comment: The only thing I have seen is the dialogue option; "Wait here". Though I don' think that all npc's have that option. And there are some followers you need to trigger certain events in some dungeons/quests

Comment: @galacticninja -- It's not really a duplicate I think (thanks for the pointer to this though) as this is more to do with stopping her following when the player abandoned (or postponed) the quest. I'd simply like to not take them with me in the first place.

Comment: @ben -- unfortunately no dialog text at all on that last companions quest for either NPC.

Comment: The worst thing is when they trigger traps that you just carefully avoided. Asking them to wait outside the dungeon seems to be the best option, as the first commenter said.

Comment: @JohnJudd I believe that unless a conversation option allows it, there is no way to prevent temporary quest followers from not going with you on their related quests. Console commands might stop them from following you but I believe this will cause bugged quests, due to the presence of the quest followers being required for some parts of the quests to trigger. Could you mention in your question what specific quest(s) and NPC followers you're having trouble with?

Comment: @galacticninja - Yeah, I'm starting to see that. I combed through the console commands but couldn't find anything specific. There was playerfollowercount but for some reason that didn't work (and I don't think it was what I was looking for anyway.) Anyway, thanks for your help.